# При нажатии кнопки назад, крашится приложение (bitmap)

Tags: android, kotlin, activity, bitmap, glide

Идея состоит в том, чтобы сделать так, чтобы 4 изображения были загружены и объединены в одну

```
Glide.with(this)
    .asBitmap()
    .load(url_hero_bg)
    .into(AppCustomTarget {
        bg_imageview_test.setImageBitmap(it)
        Glide.with(this).asBitmap().load(url_hero_man).into(AppCustomTarget{
            val bitmap1 = it
            Glide.with(this).asBitmap().load(url_hero_sword).into(AppCustomTarget{
                val bitmap2 = it
                Glide.with(this).asBitmap().load(url_hero_wear).into(AppCustomTarget{
                    val bitmap3 = it
                    val ava = overlay(bitmap1,bitmap2,bitmap3)
                    if (ava!= null){
                        setAva(ava)
                    }

                })
            })
        })
    }
    )
```

Ошибка, кажется, где-то здесь:

```
 private fun overlay(bmp1: Bitmap?, bmp2: Bitmap?,bmp3: Bitmap?): Bitmap? {
val bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(250, 280, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
val canvas = Canvas(bmOverlay)
if (bmp1!=null){
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1, Matrix(), null)
}
if (bmp2!=null){
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, Matrix(), null)
}
if (bmp3!=null){
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp3, Matrix(), null)
}

bmp1?.recycle()
bmp2?.recycle()
bmp3?.recycle()
return bmOverlay
```

}

Я стараюсь изо всех сил, чтобы исправить это, но ничего не работает..

```
/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.themarkbrutx.mymodeapp, PID: 9131
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {com.themarkbrutx.mymodeapp/com.themarkbrutx.mymodeapp.test.TestBitmapActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot obtain size for recycled Bitmap: android.graphics.Bitmap@91c6d3e[250x280] ARGB_8888
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:5111)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:5140)
    at android.app.servertransaction.DestroyActivityItem.execute(DestroyActivityItem.java:44)
```

[image: Код ошибки]

Comment: Возможно, Вам помогут какие-то решения подобных вопросов [отсюда](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/2646) или [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49738855/glide-java-lang-illegalstateexception-cannot-obtain-size-for-recycled-bitmap-a)

Comment: @Анастасия к сожалению ничего не помогло от туда...

Comment: Судя по ошибке, исключение происходит в `onDestroy()` и связано с "переработанным `Bitmap`"

Comment: @ВасяВоронцов есть способ сбросить битмап?

Comment: Возможно, [этот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30488033) поможет